# How does unfair lock have better performance than fair lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Interface *Lock* has a useful boolean fairness parameter to guarantee *fairness* in *locking* - **thread that waits for lock the longest, gets the lock first**. And I thought I wanted to use it everywhere as it prevents *starvation*. Well, not before I read that it can cost us performance.

I couldn't find an answer this question, so I hope someone can clear this up. Meaning, what is the difference between taking threads that "honor" *fairness* and threads that don't? Aren't they both stored in some "ordinary" *queue* where other waiting threads are?

Comment: You need to consider that the operating system applies algorithms when choosing threads for execution. It's not choosing randomly, it's implemented smarter of course. By using fair locking, you are bypassing those optimizations by the operating system. I'm sure that you are bypassing optimizations by the JVM as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it's not the `interface Lock` that has that `fairness`, but it's `ReentrantLock`.

The threads that issue `Lock::lock` might not be put into a queue at all, be that in `fair` or `unfair` mode.

The `unfair` mode is slightly easier to understand. In this mode, the thread that requests the lock (via calling `Lock::lock`), tries to get it immediately without getting enqueued. If that succeeds - done. It is not put into any queue, since it could get the lock. Notice that this does not care if there are already waiting threads in the queue, thus it is "unfair" (to the other already waiting threads). If it could not acquire the lock (meaning someone else has it), it is put on the queue.

On the other hand, in `fair` mode, the thread that calls `lock`, first has to check if there are already threads waiting for this lock. If there are no such threads and it can take the lock: no enqueue and take the lock. If it can't - it is enqueued.

One last point is that in *both* fair and unfair mode, the threads are put on the same queue; that is: `fair/unfair` is not about the internal representation of the queue.

Comment: Re, "...it has to be a data structure that allows random access," Yeah, but no matter the actual shape of the containers where the scheduler keeps waiting threads, everybody calls them "queues."

Comment: @SolomonSlow yeah, I did not pay attention to this until you pointed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When a lock is released, and when more than one thread is waiting for it, the thread that's been waiting the *longest* is the one that's most likely to find that memory pages that it's going want have been swapped out while it was "sleeping." The thread that's been sleeping for the least amount of time is the most likely to be "ready-to-go."

---

Apologies to @xingbin if that's what you were trying to say.